# Incompatible pointer types with Direct2D

Tags: c, windows, direct2d

I'm attempting to write a small little game engine in C using Direct2D. I'm not using the Windows C compiler; but instead using MinGW.

However any using the C declarations for `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget` I get this error:

```
graphics.c:45:37: warning: passing argument 1 of 'graphics->_target->lpVtbl->Base.BeginDraw' from incompatible pointer type [
-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     ID2D1HwndRenderTarget_BeginDraw(graphics->_target);
                                     ^
graphics.c:45:37: note: expected 'ID2D1RenderTarget * {aka struct ID2D1RenderTarget *}' but argument is of type 'ID2D1HwndRen
derTarget * {aka struct ID2D1HwndRenderTarget *}'
```

I have a `graphics_t` type defined as:

```
typedef struct graphics {
    ID2D1Factory          *_factory;
    ID2D1HwndRenderTarget *_target;
} graphics_t;
```

and the functions `graphics_begin_draw`:

```
void graphics_begin_draw(graphics_t *graphics) {
    ID2D1HwndRenderTarget_BeginDraw(graphics->_target);
}
```

`ID2D1HwndRenderTarget_BeginDraw` is a macro and from what I can gather it seems to be correctly finding the member `BeginDraw` being apart of `graphics->_target->lpVtbl->Base.BeginDraw`; however `Base.BeginDraw` takes a `ID2D1RenderTarget *` and not a `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget *`.

From what I understand about the `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget` it *inherits* from `ID2D1RenderTarget` so I can see why the `Base.BeginDraw` would expect a `ID2D1RenderTarget *`; is there a way to get around these warnings?

I could instead create a new definition of the macro that does the cast, but I'm not confident if this is the right fix:

```
#define _ID2D1HwndRenderTarget_BeginDraw(this) (this)->lpVtbl->BeginDraw((ID2D1RenderTarget *)this)
```

This is all defined in the header file which can be found [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/ci/47db312231def1a3a0c73e867f503c1ec6dc3b32/tree/mingw-w64-headers/include/d2d1.h).

Comment: I have a mantra about casting:  "every time you use a cast, a kitten dies".  Casting *usually* means you are doing something wrong.  If you were allowed to pass a ``ID2D1HwndRenderTarget`` to a ``ID2D1RenderTarget`` the compiler would let you.  Don't kill kittens :-)

Comment: @Neil You're right; I meant the cast as an attempt to naively suppress the warning without thinking about how the macro was actually working.

Comment: The C language is not exactly the most productive way to write Direct2D code.  The concept of interfaces and type inheritance are completely absent but are core to the way the api works.  The compiler has no idea whatsoever that the struct types are related, thus the warning.  You are going to get a lot more of them, consider disabling the warning to get ahead.  Or write the code in the fictional but practical "C with classes" subset that a C++ compiler supports, some odds that you'll find the smart pointer types that can wrap the interface pointer useful.

Comment: You're in for a world of pain. Using Direct2D from C is no longer supported. Indeed, it *never* was supported, but now this has materialized in that the C-style Direct2D headers are absent from the SDK (see [The oracle always tells the truth, even when it is wrong: COM method calls with a user-defined type as a return value](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220113-00/?p=106152)). It is thus unfortunate that the average response time to bad news in the MinGW project is measured in years. You're living in a time capsule that has preserved to opportunity to fail spectacularly.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for linking that article, it's enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a macro that disables the warning so I can remove some of the clutter from building.

```
#define IGNORE_INCOMPATIBLE_POINTER_TYPES(block) \
_Pragma("GCC diagnostic push") \
_Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wincompatible-pointer-types\"") \
block \
_Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")
```